# rake db:migrate not working in rails

Tags: 12.04, ruby, rails

I executed the following statements in terminal:

```
rails tickets
cd tickets
ruby script/server      //to run the app tickets on localhost:3000
ruby script/generate  scaffold ticket name:string seat:string address:text price_paid:decimal email_address:string
```

after executing the above all, I executed the migration script `rake db:migrate` and then tried to open `localhost:3000/tickets` in browser which displayed the message:

> "We're sorry, but something went wrong." instead of opening the app

Following is the output of the rake command:

```
vverma@l-vverma:~/tickets$ rake db:migrate
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /home/vverma/tickets/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#initialize is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#initialize called from /home/vverma/tickets/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/rdoctask.rb
Please install RDoc 2.4.2+ to generate documentation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar situation in trying to run a rails tutorial

All the lines headed `NOTE: Gem:: et cetera are warnings of a deprecated command going away on or after 2011-11-1 with advice on how to replace the deprecated command in coding.

The commands executed, however. Check the results.

The last lines, starting with:

> `WARNING: 'require

--et cetera are about a command that was deprecated and has already been removed. That is probably the only hard error here, the rest are just informational warnings.

Getting the correct version numbers of Ruby, Rails and gems is the only way to surmount these problems, I fear.

Good luck,
Bernie